# Writing types for a function with a different signature in NodeJS

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, hypernova

I would like to write some types for [hypernova-react](https://github.com/airbnb/hypernova-react/blob/master/src/index.js) but unfortunately it has a different type signature on the client and the server.
For the client, the types are:

```js
export function renderReact<C extends React.ComponentType>(name: string, component: C): C;

export function renderReactStatic(name: string, component: React.ComponentType): void;
```

while on the server they are

```js
export function renderReact<C extends React.ComponentType>(
    name: string,
    component: C
): (props: React.ComponentProps<C>) => string;

export function renderReactStatic<C extends React.ComponentType>(
    name: string,
    component: C
): (props: React.ComponentProps<C>) => string;
```

How do I handle this? I can't see anything in the typescript docs for checking if `window` is defined in a type guard.

Comment: Typescript can do nothing with runtime stuff, types even do not exist there. So you can define separate namespaces for server and client types like `@types/hypernova-react/server` and `@types/hypernova-react/client` for example.

Comment: How would I then make that apply to `import { renderReact } from "hypernova-react"`?